# get sales_quote model in sales/Ordercontroller magento backend

Tags: php, magento

How can I get sales_quote model in ordercontroller Magento backend? I need to get the quote details in the ordercontroller, so I'm using the following code.

```
$quote= Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteid);
```

Above query returns empty data. which is below

```
  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_quote
    [_eventObject:protected] => quote
    [_customer:protected] => 
    [_addresses:protected] => 
    [_items:protected] => 
    [_payments:protected] => 
    [_errorInfoGroups:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_preventSaving:protected] => 
    [_resourceName:protected] => sales/quote
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => sales/quote_collection
    [_cacheTag:protected] => 
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
    [_origData:protected] => 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Is there any way to get quote?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a usage question of a specific software product, here namely Magento. The Magento Q&A site seems much more fitting for that.

Comment: An just a small question back: Why do you think the code you use should do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem. After looking through the code for a while I came across this function:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::loadByIdWithoutStore()
```

I guess the regular `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::load()` function automatically attaches the current storeview to load the quote object. In this case the storeview is admin, which means no results will be found for the quote id and the returned object is empty.

In your case, this should work as expected:

```
$quote= Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteid);
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much! You just saved me hours.

Answer (score 0):

i guess, your quote id is missing, check before loading the model ,
 try this code

```
if($quoteID)
{
    try {
        $quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->load($quoteID);

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}else{
    return "no quote found";
}
```

Comment: quote id not missing.And this question is not for checkout page (Frontend).I need solution for backend (ordercontroller view page)

Comment: i had same issue what you have facing now, check the code with some different quote ids by manually

Comment: ya i had tried with manual quote ids too. the issue not fixed.