# Getting / Setting a custom column in magento table

Tags: php, mysql, magento

In my magento sales_flat_quote table I've added a new column (using ALTER TABLE) called 'simple_test_token'.

Now, I am trying to get and set the value of that column for a selected quote object. I am trying this code, which doesn't seem to get or set the value.

```
//      Get the quote
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
//      set quote value
        $quote->setAttribute(1,'simple_test_token');
//      Retrieve quote value
        $tokenValue = $quote->getAttribute('simple_test_token');
```

**EDIT**:

Resolved the issue using camel case getters and setters. Note you must use loadByIdWithoutStore() instead of load() to retrieve the correct quote object.

```
//Set attribute
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
$quote->setSimpleTestToken(1);
$quote->save()

//Get attribute
$quote->getSimpleTestToken();
```

Comment: Can you try: `$quote->setSimpleTestToken(1);`

Comment: That doesn't appear to change the value in the table. I still show that quote as having a NULL value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//      Get the quote
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
//      set quote value
        $quote->setSimpleTestToken(1);

        $quote->save()
```

// after save you can retrieve value

//      Retrieve quote value

```
 $tokenValue = $quote->getAttribute('simple_test_token');
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: This is closer. However, this appears to create a NEW quote objects. So even though I load quote ID = 270, it will create a new quote 271. It does successfully set the test column to 1, but not on the correct quote.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually I've resolved the issue. You must use loadByIdWithoutStore() instead of load to get the quote without attaching a store to it. 

related stack overflow question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546279/get-sales-quote-model-in-sales-ordercontroller-magento-backend

Comment: glad to you find solution